# How to get mutli-count of elements in Object Array by using map or other iterating functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have an Object array looks like this:

```js
const myArray = [
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 1, f1: true,  f2: true,  f3: true, f4: false, f5:false }
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 2, f1: false, f2: true,  f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false }
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 4, f1: true,  f2: false, f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false }
   ... ...
];
```

and What i want to get is:

```js
const chartData = [
  {name:'F1', value:2}, 
  {name:'F2', value:2}, 
  {name:'F3', value:3}, 
  {name:'F4', value:2},
  {name:'F5', value:0}
];
```

Now, I know how to get each element of new array by using array function:

```
const f1 = myArray.filter((x,i) => { return x.f1; }).length
const f2 = myArray.filter((x,i) => { return x.f1; }).length
...
```

Actually there are more than 5 for F* element, like F1~F20, so to caculuate everytime is not suitable way.
I want to find more simple way, Is there any way to do this by using **Javascript Array function**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `reduce` to "sum" the items. Because they're booleans, it's safe (in javascript...) to sum them using `+`:

```js
const myArray = [
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 1, f1: true,  f2: true,  f3: true, f4: false, f5:false },
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 2, f1: false, f2: true,  f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false },
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 4, f1: true,  f2: false, f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false }
];


const sumBet = (b1, b2) => ({ f1: b1.f1 + b2.f1, f2: b1.f2 + b2.f2, f3: b1.f3 + b2.f3, f4: b1.f4 + b2.f4, f5: b1.f5 + b2.f5 });

const emptyBet = () => ({ f1: false, f2: false, f3: false, f4: false, f5: false });


console.log(
  myArray.reduce(sumBet, emptyBet())
)
```

If you want it to be more generic, you can extract the key definition:

```js
const myArray = [
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 1, f1: true,  f2: true,  f3: true, f4: false, f5:false },
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 2, f1: false, f2: true,  f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false },
  { bet_line: "1",bet_type: 4, f1: true,  f2: false, f3: true, f4: true,  f5:false }
];

const sumKeys = ks => (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(ks.map(k => [k, a[k] + b[k]]));
const constKeys = (ks, c) => Object.fromEntries(ks.map(k => [k, c]));

const keys = Array.from(Array(5), (_, i) => `f${i + 1}`);
console.log(
  myArray.reduce(sumKeys(keys), constKeys(keys, 0))
)
```

Comment: Out of interest why is `emptyBet` a function returning an object rather than just an object?

Comment: Good question! It's to prevent the risk of some other piece of code (accidentally) mutating our definition of an empty bet. Another way to do it would be using `Object.freeze`.

Comment: You can use `Object.values` or `Object.entries`. The format you’ve shown in your question is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: @user3297291, I edited it(I wanted to get chart data from table Data), please give me the right answer.

Comment: Take the object my code produces and call `Object.entries(result).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }))`